# Максимальное значение setinterval и как его обойти

Tags: javascript

использую setinterval и тут у меня возник один вопрос. Как я понял, максимальное значение - `2147483647`, если указать `2147483648`, то код будет выполняться сразу.

`2147483647` ~ 35,7 минут.

**Вопрос:** Требуется, что бы код выполнялся через каждые 1 час и 1 минуту, т.е. `3600060000` мс, как правильно написать код, что бы он выполнялся корректно?

Comment: Завести setInterval на любое время и просто внутри функции проверять, прошло ли требуемое время относительно требуемой даты?

Comment: если я не ошибаюсь, то мс больше в 1000 раз)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
let now = Date.now();

setInterval(() => {
   if(Date.now() > now + 3600060000){
        console.log('tick');
        now = Date.now();
    }
}, 1000);
```